# What causes damage (equipment wear) in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls

Ok, I actually do know what causes equipment wear in Dark Souls. What I actually mean is a bit more specific.

**Note:** Before I start, I don't know the actual figures, but I do know there is a difference. However, the question isn't about those details (though it wouldn't hurt to include them in your answer).

So: when you hit an enemy, it does an amount of damage (or wear) to your equipment. Let's say it's a 1:1 - 1 hit = 1 point of equipment damage. However when you hit a wall or other object, it does more. Let's say it's a 1:2 - 1 hit = 2 points of equipment damage.

Now, there are a couple of situations here that I am uncertain of, and my only previous knowledge comes from the word of a friend, with no real backup evidence - I just went with it.

When you hit an enemy in a tight corridor, your weapon can either 1. pass through the wall (leaving a trail of sparks), or 2. hit it and rebound, at the same time it hits the enemy hitbox.

1. Your weapon passes through the wall (with a trial of sparks and hit sound effects) and hits the enemy - does it count as hitting the wall, and how much equipment damage is caused?
2. Your weapon hits the wall and bounces off (with a resounding *ding*) but still causes damage to the enemy - does it count as hitting the wall, and how much equipment damage is caused?

The last point I wanted to ask is does this apply to breakable props as well (I.e. Barrels and furniture etc.) or should I instead just roll through it all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the answer you're seeking but if I understand right, you're asking about occasions that you hit (or touch) both the wall and the enemy at the same time.

- well if your weapon **bounces back** from the wall but still hits the enemy its %100 that your weapon gets the 2 point of equipment damage however it's not tested if it becomes 3 because it hits the enemy but in my opinion it does the damage to your weapon since the enemy is in your hitbox.
- and if your weapon **grinds** to the wall (doesn't bounces back) and hits the enemy it doesn't gets the 2 damage (wall damage) but it gets a lesser damage than hitting a wall (Just like uchigatana gets damaged by grinding or touching to floor when you spam attack while looking to the floor you're standing on) and because of the enemy it takes the 1 damage so it probably takes 1-3 damage from it
- also I've looked to wikia for breakable object information and it says they haven't tested it but if you ask my opinion it shouldn't damage since you can break them by rolling (no damage needed).

I hope these things I know suits you.

Comment: That's the tricky part I wanted to try and discover - there is a rare chance that your weapon can bounce back off the wall (first bullet point) but *also* hit's the enemy. Depending on how the game works, that can lead to taking either 1 point (game thinks you hit the enemy only) *or* 3 points (game thinks you hit the wall *and* the enemy) of damage.

Comment: well hitting both the wall and the enemy situation actually happens a lot if you use large weapons with swing attacks such as zweihandler I think the chances are 1-)only counting the wall (2 damage)  2-)counting both (3 damage) I think it's counts 3 damage because  the in DS2 durability bar is visible in HUD and I noticed it decrease by hitting both wall and the enemy tons of times I also notice it decrease when I hit walls too but I barely notice when I hit an enemy. I'm looking forward to test it as soon as I can.

Comment: On the PC version, your equipment durability goes down faster if you have higher frame rates.  They kind of screwed up the port a little for DS2.

Comment: thats fixed a long time ago

Answer (score -3):

Equipment degrade when you take damage from an enemy. Either by weapons, melee or some spells. Also acid can damage your equipment. In addition weapons will also take damage, when you hit the wall or a stationary object.

Comment: I realize this. However my quesrion is a bit more in depth, and is mainly focussed on clipping issues that can occur